# What are the origins of the "Prayer For Livelihood"

Tags: prayer-book, shacharis-morning-prayer, artscroll

The **Complete Artscroll Siddur** has a section after Shacharis entitled "Readings Following Shacharis" which concludes with two sub-sections:

*Prayer For Livelihood* (two paragraphs) and *After Prayer Services - Morning and Evening* (two paragraphs plus Psalm 67)

The **Artscroll Seif Edition Weekday Siddur** does not include these, and stops with the *Ten Commandments*.

Where did the *Prayer For Livelihood* come from, and does its omission matter?

Comment: It's about 5 questions in one

Comment: To clarify @ShmuelBrin this question raises many interesting points, that would be better presented as individual questions.

Comment: I was aware that there's more than one question here, but I'm not at all sure where the best places to slice would be. I've seen my previous questions skillfully edited, so my hope is that this one will enjoy the same helpful attention.

Comment: I narrowed the question to fit with the title. Feel free, of course, to continue to [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/60762/edit) it, or to revert the changes.

Comment: Since you think the question about the Pr for L doesn't need any of the supporting detail, I'll take that and compose a separate more general question about the whole "Readings After Shacharis" section. Thank you :)

Comment: General question now [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60782/what-is-the-nature-of-the-artscroll-siddurs-readings-after-shacharis-section)