# What is the nature of the Artscroll siddur's "Readings after Shacharis" section?

Tags: shacharis-morning-prayer, artscroll

The **Complete Artscroll Siddur** has a section after Shacharis entitled "Readings Following Shacharis" which contains

(a) three lists: *The Six Rembrances*, *The Thirteen Principles of Faith*, *The Ten Commandments*

(b) three chapters, *The Chapter of Repentance* (Deut 30:1-10), *The Chapter of Reverence For G-d* (Deut 10:12 - 11:9) and *The Chapter of Manna* (Exod 16:4-36), along with short associated prayers

(c) some concluding prayers: *Prayer For Livelihood* and *After Prayer Services - Morning and Evening*, which is two paragraphs plus *Psalm 67*

(d) and finally the rubric "Some recite *Adon Olam*"

Is this section a collection of various local practices, or is it a properly constituted section, in the same manner as, say, the Shema and its blessings? In their **Seif Edition Weekday Siddur**, Artscroll have only included the three lists.

Comment: While I have seen these extras (and in some *Siddurim* a lot more than that!), it seems that a number of these are "standard" extras esp. the 10 Commandments and 13 principles of Ramba"m. I have never observed this said congregationally, so, it seems that they are not a formal part of *Shacharit* but suggested extra readings for the individual. I may be able to locate an article that discusses how and / or why they were printed in many *Siddurim*.

Comment: All of these have strong sources working in their favor: The 10 commandments USED to be part of davening until the Rabbanim took it out (due to people interpreting the rest of Torah as "less important"). The other two in the first section are about reaffirmation of principles. There are sources that discuss the merit of reciting the sections mentioned in B and C on a daily basis.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky it would be lovely to know not just the merit of each section, but what kind of history of usage they have. Is it a collection of nice ideas that, on the whole, never caught on, for example?

Comment: It varies. AFAIK, the 10 commandments is the only piece that was ever "officially" part of davening before they took it out. The six rememberences are there because they encompass daily mitzvahs and it's an optimal time to recite them. The 13 principles are a much later convention, as it's an interpretation of Rambam (though their accuracy is debated), but there's no real discussion of daily reaffirmations of faith AFAIK. The three chapters actually have an old history, probably going back to gaonic times (haven't found a source), but the associated prayers are relatively new.