# Source for Tehillim 67 after Shacharit?

Tags: tehilim-psalms, shacharis-morning-prayer

In many Artscroll Siddurim there is a perek of Tehillim after shacharit, [Tehillim 67](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.67?lang=bi). Is there any source for why this specific Perek is appropriate to say after shacharit?

Thanks!

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60782/what-is-the-nature-of-the-artscroll-siddurs-readings-after-shacharis-section

Comment: http://www.2all.co.il/web/Sites/staam/PAGE4.asp